# Google Identity Platform available MFA procedures

Tags: google-cloud-identity

The Google Identity Platform documentation only mentions MFA via SMS. Are procedures like TOTP really not supported? Is that planned for the near future?

For a sophisticated corporate application, it seems necessary to me, both for security reasons and for the cost of SMS.

Comment: I wish they had their roadmap available